# Prevent iOS chrome status bar from reappearing with front end routing

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, single-page-application

working on a react front end application with react router - was wondering if you can prevet the iOS status bar from appearing on a new front end route change.[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the only way to opt-out of hiding and showing UI in mobile browsers is to prevent the body from scrolling completely: make your whole site inside a `position: fixed; top: 0; bottom 0` container and scroll inside that. I wrote a bit more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49373506/1193622).

Comment: To clarify, the bar appears in this case because react-router has scrolled up to the top of the body.